# How do I add two variables together that have decimal values?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have created a Binary addition program that adds 2 binary numbers together and when I have converted the 2 numbers I have stored the decimal value into the variable Decimal and Decimal2.
How do I add these together??

I've tried:

```
sum = decimal+decimal2
print(sum)

add = sum(decimal+decimal2)
print(add)
```

These don't cause any errors but give me completely random answers... eg. 1010 (10) + 1111 (15) = 14.. Thanks

Comment: Could you please give clearer examples of inputs and expected and actual outputs? What is `decimal`; a string? An integer? Some custom class?

Comment: Decimal is an integer and the variable will range between 0-255

Comment: Mind showing us how decimal and decimal2 are generated?

Comment: @user3442498 then your conversion to and from binary must be incorrect, please show the appropriate sections of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to add two numbers together. Here is some code that should do that:

Python 3 version

```
num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
print(num1 + num2)
```

Python 2 version

```
num1 = int(raw_input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(raw_input("Enter second number: "))
print(num1 + num2)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Quote: `binary addition program`

Comment: Your versions do not differ

Answer (score 0):

To add two binary numbers, you can try something like this:

```
decimal1 = bin(10)
decimal2 = bin(15)
print(int(decimal1,2)+int(decimal2,2))
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe There would definitely be `TypeError` if `decimal1` and `decimal2` are  integers converted into binary

Comment: I'm not denying that; however, the fact that the OP is specifically *not* reporting an error means that your answer, starting as it does "You got the error because" is not likely to be useful!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'll just remove it then ;)